# unable to get Id from select box in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, struts2

My JSP code:

```
<s:select name="workItemVO.recipientOrg" list="carrierList" listKey="carrierName" listValue="carrierName" headerKey="" headerValue="%{selectBoxHeader}" class="form-control" maxlength="200" />
```

here's `carrierList` is a list of custom objects that have `carrierId` and `carrierName`.

The above code is very clear, if I select a value from selectbox, `carrierName` will go to the action class, and in fact I want the same.

My problem is: I want to get `carrierId` in `onChange` event of javascript. If I change above code like `"listKey="carrierId"`, I will get this value in javascript but, when the form is submitted the `carrierId` will go to the action class, not the `carrierName`. I want to send  the `carrirName` to the action class.

Comment: The above code is not very clear but you can get `carrierName` by `carrierId` in the action class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I got solution for above problem, here I used "listTitle" attribute of  to store carrierId. and onchange of the select, I am fetching it in javascript like this:

var carrierId = $('option:selected', this).attr('title');
Now what will happen like, I can use carrierId on change in javascript, as well as on submission of form carrierName will go to the action class.

```html
<s:select name="workItemVO.recipientOrg" listTitle="carrierId" list="carrierList" listKey="carrierName" listValue="carrierName" headerKey="" headerValue="%{selectBoxHeader}" class="form-control" maxlength="200" />
```